# AUTOHOTKEY changing WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE color

Tags: colors, autohotkey

How can I custom specify, or force, the color of WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE [+E0x200]? I want a much more toned down color for it.

```
CustomColor         := 000055
RequestToDisplay    := "I want to change the color of WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE"
RequestTitle        := "[REQUEST]"

GUI Request:FONT, s9 w1000 Q5, Verdana
GUI Request:COLOR, %CustomColor%, 000001
GUI Request:Add, EDIT, vMyAddress cFFFFFF r3 w400 xp-11 yp-0 -VScroll Multi WantTab t8 +E0x200 +Left
GUI Request:+LastFound +AlwaysOnTop -Caption -SysMenu
GUI Request:MARGIN, 0, 0
GUI Request:SHOW, x200 y300, %RequestTitle%

ControlSend, Edit1, %RequestToDisplay%, %RequestTitle%

return

ESC::ExitApp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or you might be looking for one of the parameter specified in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371(v=vs.85).aspx

for instance, see COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER

and for autohotkey SetSysColors dllcall see https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/36724-setsyscolors-set-system-colors/

hope this helps

steph

Comment: Yes, this AHK Forum page does apparently provide for the right DDLCall method, but after trying to set it to a few configs, nothing changed where I would have expected it to, using:

    Elementcode := 10    ;;(5, 8)
    ElementValueBGRHex := 0x000000  ;;(0xFF0000, 0x0000FF)
    DllCall("SetSysColors", "Int", 10, "Int*", Elementcode, "UInt*", ElementValueBGRHex)

Comment: ... expecting to see the INACTIVEBORDER to turn black at least for one instance (this is an on-the-fly settings, no?). Also I do not understand what the 10 stands for in contradisdisction to the value of Elementcode. What is the diference/definition of these 2 params?

Answer (score 0):

CP,

to my understanding, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE is a window style (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx).
to change the color of the edge that this window style produces, is an entire other question.
i would not know how to formulate this precise question.
but looking at your autohotkey code ([AUTOHOTKEY changing WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621577/autohotkey-changing-ws-ex-clientedge-color)), i see that CustomColor := 000055, to me it looks like an hexadecimal color value specified in a decimal way, that is without the 0x prefix (but that would be mandatory in C/C++)

SP.

Answer (score 0):

in my C/C++ understanding one changes window's elements color calling SetSysColors() function see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724940(v=vs.85).aspx for an example.

in that example, COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION is used to specify the window border element's color, it might be the one you are looking for.